# Cordova Native Storage Plugin undefined in app iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, nuxt.js

I've installed the latest version of the Cordova Native Storage plugin (https://github.com/TheCocoaProject/cordova-plugin-nativestorage) into my Cordova / Nuxt JS project. I'm trying to store some data when I click a button, and alert the data back when a different button is clicked:

```html
<template>
  <div class="fill-height has-safe-area-top">
    <v-container>
      <v-layout row pb-2>
        <v-flex>
          <h1>Native storage test</h1>
          <v-btn @click="storeData">Store</v-btn>
          <v-btn @click="getData">Get</v-btn>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {

    storeData() {
      NativeStorage.initWithSuiteName("suitename");
      NativeStorage.setItem("reference_to_value", "my value");
    },

    getData() {
      alert(NativeStorage.getItem("reference_to_value"))
    }

  }
}
</script>
```

This seems to return `undefined` on the `alert()` when testing on a physical device compiled in Xcode 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we can read on documentation, setItem method have a success and error callback function, I therefore deduce that this function is asynchronous.

```
NativeStorage.setItem("reference_to_value",<value>, <success-callback>, <error-callback>);
```

I think that you press too quickly on the second button and that the first method has not finished writing its variable in the native storage of the phone

### Try something like that :

```
storeData() {
  NativeStorage.initWithSuiteName("suitename");
  NativeStorage.setItem("reference_to_value", "my value", () => {
      alert("SUCCESS");
  }, () => {
      alert("ERROR");
  });
},
```

And don't touch anything while alert didn't showed

getItem is also "callback" method who return nothing. You should handle the callback of this function like this :

```
getData() {
    NativeStorage.getItem("reference_to_value", (value) => {
        alert(value);
    }, () => {
        alert("ERROR");
    });
}
```

Comment: I've implemented this and it seems to work great for Android, however, with iOS, after storing to Native Storage once and force-closing the app, the native storage has been cleared upon reopening the app. For Android, this isn't the case